# Is it possible to make a function parameter accept 2 or more type?

Tags: python, types

How do you create a function whose arguments accepts 2 or even more data types. I have a Product class as follows

```py
class Product:
      def __init__(self, name: str, price: int | float)
          self.product = {'name': name, 'price': price)
```

This results into a TypeError

```sh
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'
```

Then I try using or operator, but it picks up `type int` only

How can I make sure that it accepts both int and float

Comment: Besides the (correct) answer, this will/already work in [Python 3.10](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in typing this is done with [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union):

```
from typing import Union

class Product:
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: Union[int, float])
        self.product = {'name': name, 'price': price)
```

Note, as you can read from the documentation, this is possible with `int | float`, but only from version Python 3.10 onwards. As most users are not yet on Python 3.10, in practice people still tend to use `Union[int, float]`.
However, `int | float` is preferred if you do not care about supporting versions below Python 3.10.

Comment: *"in practice people still tend to use Union[int, float]"* The main reason for still using `Union` (or any other "older" syntax) is to support older Python versions in the same code base (backward compatibility).

Comment: That is correct. My Python modules use `Union` such that the modules can be supported from Python 3.6 onwards, to reach the largest audience possible. If I planned to only use a project for myself, I would use `int | float`, as my main Python version is 3.10 as of now. I've edited my comment to include that `int | float` is preferred if it does not cause compatibility issues.